# How to combine files with paste and save to one of the files that is combined?

Tags: unix, paste

Whenever I try to append to a file (with a table with the delimiter ";") with new data using the paste command, it never does what I intend to do.

I have tried the following;

```
paste -d";" Grades_HW1 Grades > Grades
```

but it overwrites the "Grades" file with Grades_HW1; when I try to append instead with ">>", it adds new lines to the bottom. How could I use paste to combine files and update it to the file?

Comment: Output to a temp file and then rename it.

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2Ffoo.2Fbar.2F_.3E_file